# Finding the minimum of $f(x)=3x^2+4y^2+4xy-11x-6y$ where $x$ and $y$ are reals.

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, quadratics

Question:

> Find the minimum of $f(x, y)=3x^2+4y^2+4xy-11x-6y$ where $x$ and $y$ are reals and characterise the instances of equality.

My approach:

My first thought was to factorise this into a square. However, that is clearly not possible. AM-GM and Jenson's does not apply here  due to the $-11x-6y$. Cauchy-Schwarz and other inequalities do not seem to apply either. According to [dcode.fr](https://www.dcode.fr/minimum-function), the minimum is $-\dfrac{41}{4}$ and equality is achieved when $x=2$ and $y=-\frac{1}{4}$, but I do not know how to prove this. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You just need to take the partial derivatives wrt $x$ and wrt $y$. Set equal to zero (both) and solve them simultaneously (by rearranging and substituting)

Comment: i.e. your first equation is $6x+4y-11=0$

Comment: For an arbitrary continuous function, the global minimum is going to be one of the local minima or an endpoint

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When the minimum of $f(x, y)$ is achieved, by definition, the derivative of $f(x, y)$ with respect to both $x$ and $y$ must be $0$ (when the other is held constant). Hence, it suffices to find the derivative of $f(x, y)$ with respect to both $x$ and $y$.

The derivative of $f(x, y)$ with respect to $x$ is
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[3x^2+4y^2+4xy-11x-6y\right] \\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[3x^2+(4y-11)x+(4y^2-6y)\right] \\
&=6x+4y-11 & \text{since }y\text{ is held constant}
\end{align}$$

Similarly, the derivative of $f(x, y)$ with respect to $y$ is
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[3x^2+4y^2+4xy-11x-6y\right] \\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[4y^2+(4x-6)y+(3x^2-11x)\right] \\
&=8y+4x-6 & \text{since }x\text{ is held constant}
\end{align}$$

Suppose that the minimum of $f(x, y)$ is achieved when $(x, y)=(x_0, y_0)$. Then, we will have

$$
\begin{cases}
6x_0+4y_0=11 \\
4x_0+8y_0=6 \\
\end{cases} \\
\implies \begin{cases}
x_0=2 \\
y_0=-\frac{1}{4} \\
\end{cases}
$$

Now, we can substitute this back into $f(x, y)$ to get $$f(x_0, y_0)=-10\frac{1}{4}$$

Now, it suffices to prove that this is indeed the global minimum. Consider the double partial derivative of $f(x, y)$.

The double derivative of $f(x, y)$ with respect to $x$ is
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[6x+4y-11\right] \\
&=6
\end{align}$$

Similarly, the double derivative of $f(x, y)$ with respect to $y$ is
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[8y+4x-6\right] \\
&=8
\end{align}$$

Lastly, the double derivative of $f(x, y)$ with respect to $xy$ is
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(8y+4x-6\right) \\
&=4
\end{align}$$

Now, consider the Hessian matrix. Its determinant will be $6\times8-(4)^2=32>0$. Coupled with the fact that $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}>0$, we can conclude that $-10\frac{1}{4}$ is indeed the local minimum. However, since $f(x, y)$ is also strictly convex, $-10\frac{1}{4}$ is also the global minimum.

Hence, the minimum of $f(x, y)$ is $-10\frac{1}{4}$ with equality if and only if $x=2$ and $y=-\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: "However, by inspecting the values of $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, we can clearly see that this is the minimum" : can you explain ?

Comment: If $x$ decreases, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ will be less than $0$ and vice versa and similarly for $y$. Since OP tagged this as contest math, and as someone who pursues contest math, this is considered trivial in contests.

Comment: You seem to miss that it may have no global minimum (either no minimum at all, either only local minima).

Comment: This is splendid +1

Comment: I maintain that this answer is not clear at all, since you don't prove that the stationnary point you found is a global minimum. I am not convinced at all by the emphatic use of the words "clearly" or "trivial", as long as I don't see any arguments.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Fine, I have included the proof that the stationary point is a global minimum, I hope you're happy.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Do you mind writing out a full solution? I'm interested to know how a full proof will look like.

Comment: @3point1415 I wrote an answer !

Answer (score 10):

By direct calculation, one has
\begin{align*} 
f(x,y) & = 3x^2+4y^2+4xy-11x-6y \\
& = (2y+x)^2 +2x^2 - 11x - 6y \\
& = \left(2y+x - \dfrac{3}{2} \right)^2 +2x^2-8x - \dfrac{9}{4} \\
& = \left(2y+x - \dfrac{3}{2} \right)^2 +2\left(x-2 \right)^2 - \dfrac{41}{4} 
\end{align*}

For every $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, one has directly $f(x,y) \geq -\dfrac{41}{4}$.

And moreover, one deduces that
\begin{align*} 
f(x,y) = -\dfrac{41}{4} & \Longleftrightarrow  \left(2y+x - \dfrac{3}{2} \right)^2 +2\left(x-2 \right)^2 - \dfrac{41}{4}  =  - \dfrac{41}{4}   \\
& \Longleftrightarrow  \left(2y+x - \dfrac{3}{2} \right)^2 +2\left(x-2 \right)^2 =0 
\end{align*}

so $f(x,y) = -\dfrac{41}{4} \Longleftrightarrow  \left\lbrace \begin{array}{l} 2y+x - \dfrac{3}{2}=0 \\ x-2 = 0 \end{array} \right. \Longleftrightarrow  \left\lbrace \begin{array}{l} x=2 \\ y = -\dfrac{1}{4}\end{array} \right.$

Comment: I wonder why this was downvoted, it is a correct solution (+1).

Answer (score 6):

Solving
$$
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 6x + 4x -11 = 0 \\
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 4x + 8y -6 = 0 \\
$$
shows that $(x_0, y_0) = (2, -1/4)$ is a stationary point and a possible candidate for the minimum. Now
$$
 f(u + 2 , v - \frac 14) = 3 u^2 + 4 v^2+4 uv- \frac{41}{4}
= 2 u^2 + (u+2v)^2 - \frac{41}{4} 
$$
shows that $f(x, y) \ge - \frac{41}{4}$
with equality if and only if $u=v=0$, so that $(2, -1/4)$ is the global minimum.

*Remark:* It is not a coincidence that $f(x, y)$ can be written as a “sum of squares” plus the minimal value. This is generally true for quadratic functions of the form
$$
f(x,y)= Ax^2+2Bxy +Cy^2 +2Dx + 2Ey + F
$$
with $A > 0$ and $B^2 < AC$, see for example [Finding minimum value of a function of two variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1147293/42969) or [Help in justifying that $f(a,b)$ is a global minimum](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2064034/42969).

One can also argue that $f$ is *strictly convex* because the [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix), in this case
$$
 H_f = \begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} && \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \\
 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} && \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} \\
\end{pmatrix}
=  \begin{pmatrix}
 6 & 4 \\ 4 & 8
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is positive definite everywhere. (Strictly) convex functions have the property that any stationary point is a (strict) global minimum.

Answer (score 4):

In this answer, we apply the $\color{#c00}{\Delta}$ method, which is one of the *general* high school level methods that can work quickly for our purposes .

---

Let

$$\begin{align}3x^2\!+\!4y^2\!&+\!4xy\!-\!11x\!-\!6y\!=\!a\end{align}$$

Let's rearrange the equation as a quadratic equation with respect to $\color{#c00}{x}$ :

$$\begin{align}3\color{#c00}{x}^2\!+\!\color{#c00}{x}(4y\!-\!11)\!&+\!(4y^2\!-\!6y\!-\!a)\!=\!0\end{align}$$

Then, we determine the discriminant $\Delta_{\color{#c00}{x}}$ :

$$
\begin{align}\Delta_{\color{#c00}{x}}&=-32\color{#0a0}{y}^2-16\color{#0a0}{y}+(121+12a)\\
&=-\left(32\color{#0a0}{y}^2+16\color{#0a0}{y}-(121+12a)\right)\\
&≥0\end{align}
$$

We recall that, if $\Delta_{\color{#0a0}{y}}<0$, then $\Delta_{\color{#c00}{x}}<0$ . A contradiction . Therefore, we have $\Delta_{\color{#0a0}{y}}≥0$. Thus,

$$
\begin{align}&\Delta_{\color{#0a0}{y}}=64+32(121+12 a)≥0\\
\implies &a≥-\frac {41}{4}\thinspace .
\end{align}
$$

which completes the answer .

Answer (score 2):

Another way.

Let $x=2a$ and $y=-\frac{1}{4}b$.

Thus, $$3x^2+4y^2+4xy-11x-6y=12a^2+\frac{1}{4}b^2-2ab-22a+\frac{3}{2}b=$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}(48a^2-8ab+b^2-88a+6b)=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{3}(12a-b-11)^2-\frac{(b+11)^2}{3}+b^2+6b\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{12}\left((12a-b-11)^2+2b^2-4b-121\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{12}\left((12a-b-11)^2+2(b-1)^2-123\right)\geq-\frac{123}{12}=-\frac{41}{4}.$$
The equality occurs for $a=b=1,$ which says that we got a minimal value.

Comment: Isn't that exactly the same method as my answer ? Except that you expressed everything in terms of your new variables $a$ and $b$ ? (this works perfectly, though)

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I did not see your solution. In any case, my way is better because to work with $a=b=1$ is easier than with $(x,y)=\left(2,-\frac{1}{4}\right).$ But I agree our ways are similar.

Comment: It is your opinion, but personnally, I think that your calculations are more complicated than mine.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe  I added alternate high school level method .

Answer (score 0):

$$f_x=6x+4y-11, \, f_y=8y+4x-6.$$ They are zero only at $x=2, $ $y=-1/4$, so its our candidate to extremum. Now $$f_{xx}=6,\,f_{xy}=4\,, f_{yy}=8, $$ so the jacobian is $48-16>0$, so our point is a global minimum.

Comment: Who downvoted this? I have given you an upvote to make up for it.

Comment: I really dont understand this website. Thanks btw

Comment: Three things that can explain the downvotes : do you really mean "jacobian" ? how does the positivity of this determinant leads to a minimum ? can you really deduce that the minimum is global (and not only local) ?

Comment: The Jacobian is the determinant of the Jacobi matrix, at least that how I was teached. The other details are basic theory of differntial calculus, which I think it shouldnt be explained here

Comment: @GuillermoGarcíaSáez You are at least confuding "jacobian matrix" with "hessian matrix". The other details are maybe basic, but they are wrong as you state them : indeed, the determinant of the hessian matrix is not sufficient to ensure that you have a minimum, you must check that the matrix is positive-definite ; and even if it is the case, it only gives you the existence of a *local* minimum. Therefore your answer has serious issues.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I think that he's referring to the hessian matrix, but if the determinant of the hessian matrix is $>0$ and $f_{xx}$ is positive we can say that the point is a local minimum. Can't we?

Comment: @SineoftheTime You are right, but I don't see the fact that $f_{xx}$ is positive, so the argument is incomplete ; and more important, it only gives the existence of a local minimum and not of a global one.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe sure, here it's only a local minimum. Since $f_{xx}=6 >0$ and the determinant is positive, then the hessian is positive defined